# Locking from a sent parameter?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parameters, locking

Can I lock MyClass from ThreadRunner.RunThread when sending it as an argument?

```
MyClass{
    private static object locker = new object();
    public void RunThreads{
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            ThreadRunner.RunThread(locker);
        }
    }
}
```

Is this kosher, or should I have the logic of RunThread in MyClass so I don't have to pass the locker object?

Comment: you are providing far too little information... what exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: To answer your question, MyClass is running the method ThreadRunner.RunThread.  For the purpose of my script, I need to lock MyClass from each thread during a critical operation.  What I'm wondering is if there are any context issues with sending my locker object to the RunThread method, and locking MyClass from that context.  Hope that makes sense, please let me know what other information I can provide or if anything is unclear.  Thanks.

Comment: it is still not fully clear - is the lock really Type-related (as the static field suggests) OR do you want the lock to be instance-specific ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Edit**: I corrected the `const` stop the downvotes please!

Since `locker` is static, it's better to just declare it as:

```
public static readonly object locker = new object();
```

since lock objects should be constant anyway, and use it inside the thread code as:

```
MyClass.locker
```

that way you don't need to pass it.

Comment: You can't declare object const in C#

Comment: This won't compile for many reasons: `const` cannot be `static` and the only initializers for const reference types are strings and null (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Hah, and I actually declared it `readonly` the first time because I wasn't sure if `const` was correct. :)))

Comment: Ok, can I get my points back now? I still maintain that this solution is correct minus the `const` part...

Comment: Tudor, this would requre MyClass to be sent to the method RunThread.  This is exactly what I'm unsure about, can I pass the locker (through MyClass or by itself) to RunThread and have it lock properly from that context?

Comment: @sooprise, No, you don't need to pass the class. The class itself is visible as long as you are not in a different namespace. All you have write is `MyClass.locker`.

Comment: MyClass will be visible in the same namespace, but not a specific instance of MyClass that I would want to lock, correct?

Comment: @sooprise: But I thought you wanted to lock on the static field `locker`, not on an instance of `MyClass`. `locker` is the same object for all instances of `MyClass` so you don't need a specific instance to access it.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I think the static part is what's important, thanks!